# Plot time on Y-axis and users on X-axis Highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I have data of users with time for each user as follows:

Time Data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:46:01
    [1] => 08:52:57
)
```

User Data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => User1
    [1] => User2
)
```

I need to plot a graph with Time on Y-Axis and Users on X-Axis in Highcharts. I am able to create graph by converting time to sec in PHP and plotting it see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqyj7o0q/). But unable to plot it in time format on the graph. Please help. Thanks.

**Update**
I have an array of time of all users like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:46:01
    [1] => 08:52:57
)
```

I need to pass this data to highcharts jquery code. So how can I convert above array to work in previous fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Datetime format, you need to assign dates too. There is nothing such as a time format.

For that you can assign a date for your times and edit the options to show only the hours and minutes.

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pqyj7o0q/1/

by adding:

```
type: 'datetime'
min: Date.UTC(Year, month, day),
max: Date.UTC(Year, month, day)
```

to your `yAxis` and also changing your data to date formats like above.

Comment: How is it applicable in highcharts? is there any example?

Comment: I am trying to convert time array to data string which is to be passed to series.data. But unable to make it. can you help please?

Comment: time array to data string?? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: As there is not static data. I have PHP array which have time for each user. So how can I convert it to Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10 , 9 , 46 , 01)

Comment: Date.UTC(YourDate.getFullYear(), YourDate.getMonth(), YourDate.getDate(), YourDate.getHour(), YourDate.getMinute(), YourDate.getSeconds())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64705/discussion-between-raeen-hashemi-and--).

Comment: Chat is disable by our office Firewall :(. I have used mktime() to convert data which gives me Array
(
    [0] => 1415674711
    [1] => 1415674711)

Comment: Or this JSON {"0":1415674711,"1":1415674711}. What is the output of Date.UTC(...)?

Comment: Date.UTC(2014,11,11) => 1418256000000 - its the milliseconds difference of the specified date with the date Date.UTC(1969,12,1) => 0

Comment: I think the numbers you have are the seconds difference. Just multiply by 1000 and it should be OK.